# No error Lint even if the same id is used in <include> tag of the xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I used two `<include>` tags in the activity_main.xml and then i just set same id for the two `<include>` tags. But There is no error Lint. How is it possible? I'm trying to figure this out but can't. 
please check all the layout files below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <include
      android:id="@+id/include1" <-- same id!!!
      layout="@layout/item1" />

  <include
      android:id="@+id/include1" <-- same id!!!
      layout="@layout/item2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item1.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT1"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
</merge>
```

**item2.xml**

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT2"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</merge>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: @Zain yes, and there were no problem. but if i use Viewbinding, the system tells me same id error like this `Found data binding error(s): [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cinclude id\u003d\u0027@+id/include1\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","pos":[{"line0":8,"col0":4,"line1":10,"col1":32}]}`